# Get count of friend requests in Facebook

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I am using Facebook Development Toolkit for my Facebook Canvas Application (ASP .NET).

How can I get the count of friend requests of user (current user)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem.

You can do it by using [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend_request).
Attention! Your application must have [read_requests permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions). How to get [such permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#requesting-extended-permissions).